# How to receive MultipartFormDataContent in API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, httpclient, iformfile

Net core application. I have one rest API which will send files to another API.

Below is the logic inside first API to send files to second API.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await _tokenService.GetToken());
                    MultipartFormDataContent multipartFormData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    string contentJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
                    HttpContent data = new StringContent(contentJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    multipartFormData.Add(data, "data");
                    foreach (var file in fileList)
                    {
                        if (file.Length <= 0)
                            continue;
                        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                        multipartFormData.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream())
                        {
                            Headers =
                            {
                        ContentLength = file.Length,
                        ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType)
                            }
                        }, "File", fileName);
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44370/apisendfile", multipartFormData);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
```

I have second API as below

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> SendMail([FromBody] MultipartFormDataContent formDataContent)
        {
        }
```

When I debug in my first API I receive error

> Unsupported Media Type

I am trying all the way to figure it out but could not succeed. Can someone help me to identify this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Share your full controller code.

Comment: Hi Md Farid Uddin. I have shared first api code above and in second api am saving file but my problem is first tries to call second api and fails with unsupported media type.

Comment: I am not sure you are having problem on `Posting Multipart` or receiving `Multipart` data? You could read our [offical document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2#file-upload)

Comment: Hi HD Farid Uddin, I am having trouble with receiving multipat

Comment: it must be not frombody; no needs to specify from what if you use default corect file or bytes submit; see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try following way,

***Web API Controller:***

```
        [HttpPost]
        public string UploadMultipartFile()
        {
            var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                var path = Path.Combine(
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MrPerfectMaltipartFolder"),
                    fileName
                );

                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

            return file != null ? "/MrPerfectMaltipartFolder/" + file.FileName : null;
        }
```

***Folder Location:***

[image]

***Tested on Post Man:***

[image]

***Open Folder Location:***

[image]

***File Uploaded:***

[image]

***For N Type of Multipart Data Upload:***

```
    [HttpPost]
    public object UploadMultipartFileList()
    {
        var uploadedFilesName = new List<string>();
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            int count = 0;
           
            foreach (var item in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
            {


                var getFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[count];
                if (getFile != null)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(getFile.FileName);

                    var path = Path.Combine(
                        HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MrPerfectMaltipartFolder"),
                        fileName
                    );

                    getFile.SaveAs(path);
                }
                count++;
                string file = "/MrPerfectMaltipartFolder/" + getFile.FileName;
                uploadedFilesName.Add(file);
            }
        }




        return uploadedFilesName;
    }
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Example Both Data and File:***

```
        [HttpPost]
        public object UploadMultipartFileList()
        {
            HttpRequest multipartRquest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
          
           //General Data Part
            string engineerName = multipartRquest.Form["EngineerName"];
            string engineerEmail = multipartRquest.Form["EngineerEmail"];

            //File Upload Part
            var FilesName = new List<string>();
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                int count = 0;
               
                foreach (var item in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
                {


                    var getFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[count];
                    if (getFile != null)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(getFile.FileName);

                        var path = Path.Combine(
                            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MrPerfectMaltipartFolder"),
                            fileName
                        );

                        getFile.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                    count++;
                    string file = "/MrPerfectMaltipartFolder/" + getFile.FileName;
                    FilesName.Add(file);
                }
            }




            return FilesName;
        }
```

***Request Format:***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Hope it would resolve your problem. Feel free to share if you still encounter any issues.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count will read files but also i am sending other data(like model) i request. So how can i get all these data?

Comment: No worries, see the updated answer, now on, all the questions should be fit in at once so that it would be great for you and the contributor. Have a great day.

Comment: this old bad style to complicated you use API in incorrect way

Comment: The solution is usually provided as per shared code and scenario. I didn't consider the way but how to resolve the scenario. You could [`follow this way either`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72442567/upload-pic-in-model-asp-net-core/72443710#72443710)

Answer (score 0):

Correct API style :

```
            [HttpPost("logfiles")] // etc
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddLogFile(IFormFile reportFile)
        {
            //UploadFile with any options with correct property Name = "ReportFile"
// all assigment will do framework itself in default impl
            if (reportFile == null || reportFile.Length <= 0)
            {
```

Submit client side style :

```
using (MultipartFormDataContent httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
      {
// read bytes from memstream etc
//...
    httpContent.Add((HttpContent) bytes, "ReportFile", "test.log");
```