# Upload pic in Model ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my controller of uploading or adding picture in it

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("MemberId,Name,Gender,DOB,MaritalStatus,Address,PhoneNo,Skills,Hobbies,JobTitle,Technology")] Member member)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(member.ImageName != null)
            {
                string folder = "ImageName/Cover";
                folder += member.ImageName.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string serverFolder =Path.Combine(_webHostEnviroment.WebRootPath, folder);
            }

            _context.Add(member);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(member);
}
```

This is the model class:

```
public class Member
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public string? MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    public string? Address { get; set; }

    public long PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public string? Skills { get; set; }
    public string? Hobbies { get; set; }

    public string? JobTitle { get; set; }

    public string? Technology { get; set; }

    public string? ImageName { get; set; }

    public Team? Team { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeamMember>? TeamMembers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}
```

This is my html page

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
       <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Member Image</label>
         <div class="col-md-10">
           <input class="form-control" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" />
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to upload a picture in I add functionality in controller but it shows an error; I will try this thing first time and I don't not how to fix this error - I try but nothing will happen.

Image/cover folder

[image]

Comment: Could you please include your `controller code snippet` as well instead of screenshot?

Comment: Done i add controller in Code snippet

Comment: Thanks for the update, could you please tell more, about what `error` you are getting in addition, your `view` is also missing which doesn't match your given model.

Comment: In view Member Image is ImageName i define image name in modal

Comment: i follow some documentation or video for uploading picture but when i write filename in controller it give error string doesn't contain definition  of filename and no accesable extension method

Comment: So what seems from your description, basically you want to upload a member image into a folder right?

Comment: Not sure which document you are referring to, could you share us `"ImageName/Cover"` details within your project, need to have a look at the screenshot where it belongs to?

Comment: yes i want to Upload Member Image

Comment: Alright got your expectations, I am trying to assist you.

Comment: thanks So much and i add image/Cover folder it is empty

Comment: You could try the given solution I hope it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to upload a picture in I add functionality in controller but it shows an error; I will try this thing first time and I don't not how to fix this error - I try but nothing will happen?

First of all you should use  `IFormFile photo` property to handle your `image upload` option. So at your current design, when would you add `IFormFile` property it will yell at you `OnModelCreating` so you should use `viewModel` here to handle that easily. here is the complete demo for you.

**Your current model**:

```cs
public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        public string? ImageName { get; set; }
       
       
    }
```

**Make a ViewModel like this**:

```cs
public class MemberViewModel
    {
        public Member Member { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** Reason for `MemberViewModel` is when you add `IFormFile` property within your existing model it will restrict you and there are an additional hassle to overcome that rather `ViewMdoel` will make that easy for you.

**Controller**:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMember(MemberViewModel model, IFormFile photo)
        {
            if (photo == null || photo.Length == 0)
            {
                return Content("File not selected");
            }
            var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ImageName/Cover", photo.FileName);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }

            model.Member.ImageName = photo.FileName;

            if (model != null)
            {
                var member = new Member
                {
                    Name = model.Member.Name,
                    Gender = model.Member.Gender,
                    DOB = model.Member.DOB,
                    ImageName = model.Member.ImageName,
                    ImageLocation = path,
                };
                _context.Add(member);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("MemberList");

        }
```

**Note:** Point to remember here, firstly we are saving the image in `folder` then we are taking that `image name` and `location` for saving into `database` as we have `viewModel` which is different than our `domain model` so we are binding `view model` to our `domain model`.

**View**:

```cs
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.MemberViewModel
<div>
    <form asp-action="CreateMember" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div><input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.MemberId" />
        <div>
            <h4><strong>Member Details</strong> </h4>

            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">

                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Member.Name"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="Member.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter member name" /><span asp-validation-for="Member.Name"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Member.Gender"></label></th>
               
                    <td>
                        <select asp-for="Member.Gender" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Member.Gender"></span>
                
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Member.DOB"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="Member.DOB" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter animal category" /><span asp-validation-for="Member.DOB"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Photo"></label></th>
                    <td>
                         <strong>Upload New File</strong> <div id="chooseFile"><input type="file" name="photo"  accept="image/*" /></div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:107px">Save Info</button></th>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Back To List", "MemberList", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</th>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

**Output:**

Here is the output of above example

[image]

Comment: can i add ImageLocation in member model because when i use ImageLocation it show member does not contain Image location

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

model.Member.ImageName = photo.FileName;

Comment: if i add `@model TeamManagement.ViewModel.MemberViewModel`
 in view page all colum will show memberview model does not contain

Comment: First, try my solution. Once you are successfully able to run it then review the code for minutes, then start your modification In addition, your `ViewModel` should only add your existing `Member Model` and `IFormFile? Photo` property. So finally it should be like `public class MemberViewModel { public Member Member { get; set; } public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; } }`

Comment: in which object image can store

Comment: Did you run my solution at your end? Did you noticed `photo.FileName` it will help us to retrieve image from `input type="file" name="photo"  accept="image/*"` `HTML` then will bind the `imageName` with your `Member.ImageName` property. In my code it's clearly stated that along with a note. Which one made you confused?

Comment: **Special note for you**, do not try to modify the full code as a whole. Do it steps by step and gradually. First, try to get what I did. Firstly run the given solution successfully.

Comment: in my project i created bootstrap cards  and i want member pics shown in bootstrap cards i does not how i add image name like this(            `<img class="card-img-top" src="@Member.ImageName" alt="Card image">`
)

Comment: Did you run my solution or not? Did you able to save the image into your database? First, you have to save it then the displaying steps come in. You should access your image like this `<img src="~/ImageName/Cover/@Member.ImageName"class="rounded-square" height="50" width="75"
style="border:1px"
asp-append-version="true" accept="image/*" />` as your image location is like `"ImageName/Cover"`

Comment: yes i able to save img in database

Comment: That's great,  so your one problem has been resolved. Now could you please post a new question with your current blockings and issue. So that it can be checked there.

Comment: yes picture show on running but now my problem is how to add image on existing member because when i create new it working but when i edit it will not shown

Comment: No worries, its not working, because you haven't set it correctly, post a new question, will check there as the problem is different. Also included your full code and expectation what is your current problem.

Comment: no i new here so i does not know about the feature of stackoverflow

Comment: Did you posted new question about your current problem?

Comment: can i post whole controller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72445894/18812706 current problem

Answer (score 0):

You need add an attribute

```
public IformFile pic{get;set;}
```

in your member class

And delete the bind attribute in your action,So that you could bind your member model

Comment: The property 'Member.pic' is of an interface type ('IFormFile'). If it is a navigation, manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type. Otherwise, ignore the property using the [NotMapped] attribute or 'Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating' this error occure when i migrate

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use IFormFile for your image property like;

I didn't add any IFormFile property to my class that I add to my DbContext, I handled it by using it in a ViewModel and I used that ViewModel on my adding page as a Model, this is the important point I guess...

[image: IMAGE PROPERTY]

I keep the file path in AppSettings.json so I get them from there

This is the code how I upload the image to that file path...

[image]

This is the adding page view; (You don't have to use 'multiple' attribute if you will upload only one picture, if you will you must change image property from IFormFile to IFormFile[] )

[image: Adding picture html view]

I hope these help ! :)

Comment: Thanks bro i have some one more problem if you are able to help

Comment: Of course, what is the problem

Comment: i create identity in my project after creating identity it will create only cshtml.cs file but doesn't create cshtml file but when i run the project it will show login page i  does not found the cshtml. file

Comment: I don't understand bro, please explain more open or send me a message with more detail with pictures, i would like to help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72388287/18812706  i add question recently