# How to access a specific column in a database using multiple view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to access multiple models from a database on a single view. I created a view model class, composed of an IEnumerable of both of my models that represents two tables in my database. My problem comes into play when it says

> CS106 IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for
> 'ProfilePicture' and no accessible extension method 'ProfilePicture'
> accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable'
> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)

The way I'm calling it is by typing @Model.ApplicationUserVM.ProfilePicture. If that doesn't work, how else am I supposed to retrieve the information?

View:

```
@using Website_friend_feature.Models;
@model ProfilePictureViewModel
@{
            Layout = null;


}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



.....  




  <!-- The Grid -->
  <div class="w3-row">
    <!-- Left Column -->
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <!-- Profile -->
      <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white">
        <div class="w3-container">
         <p class="w3-center"><img src=@Model.ApplicationUserVM.ProfilePicture class="w3-circle" style="height:106px;width:106px" alt="Avatar"></p>
         <h4 class="w3-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">@Model.ApplicationUserVM.FirstName @Model.ApplicationUserVM.LastName</h4>
         <h2 style="color: lightgray; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; margin-top: 0px; "> @@@Model.ApplicationUserVM.UserName</h2>
```

Models:

ApplicationUser:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Website_friend_feature.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       [PersonalData]
       [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(1000)")]
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }

    }
}
```

ProfilePicture:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Website_friend_feature.Models
{
    public class ProfilePicture
    {
        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [DisplayName("Upload Profile Picture")]
        public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }

        public string Picture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Website_friend_feature.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace Website_friend_feature.Models
{
    public class ProfilePictureViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<ProfilePicture> ProfilePictureVM{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUserVM { get; set; }
    }
}
```

controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Website_friend_feature.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Website_friend_feature.Models;

namespace Website_friend_feature.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {

        
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
       

        public UserController (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            
            _userManager = userManager;

            
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Profile(String id) 
        
        {
            

            
            if (id == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(id);
            if (user is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(user);
        }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share how you are binding `ProfilePictureViewModel`  while passing it to `view`? How you are populating this?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm using IEnumerbales and trying to call it by using Model.ApplicationUser.FirstName

Comment: That's I understand from your code, I want to know how you are getting data here `@model ProfilePictureViewModel`  could you share your `controller` as well?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I just updated with the controller

Comment: No where I've seen `ProfilePictureViewModel` model binding, how would you get data into your view, Hows your `ApplicationUser`  class details? What your `_userManager.FindByNameAsync` returns? First you have to fetch data from database then you to bind data into your `ProfilePictureViewModel` then need to iterate into your view. [`You can have a look at this reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72442567/upload-pic-in-model-asp-net-core/72443710#72443710) . Feel free to share if any further concern remains.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron that wasn't my original concern. It was how to properly call the model in the view. But i figured it out. It was not until i ran the program till I noticed that I didn't properly set up the controller. What you see was my original setup for one model. But now i got two. And im trying to figure out how do I call the Id

Comment: Hi @roger blinkins, IF you wanna use model in your view, you need to pass it from controller to view first, Then in your View, Because the type of ProfilePictureVM is `IEnumerable`, you can't just use `@Model.ApplicationUserVM.ProfilePicture` directly, you need to use `foreach()` to get each item, then use the item.

Comment: @XinranShen the tutorial I was looking at a tutorial that used IEnumerable, so I thought I had to use that. Then i realized that i don't have to use this `public IEnumerable<ProfilePicture> ProfilePictureVM{ get; set; }` I can use this `public ProfilePicture ProfilePictureVM{ get; set; }` and it would work as normal

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear. You can't directly access the `ProfilePicture` from an `IEnumerable<ApplicationUserVM>`.

Instead, you need to get a specific T item from `IEnumerable<T>` in order to access the properties from `T`.

Either one of these approaches:

With indexer:

```
@Model.ApplicationUserVM[0].ProfilePicture
```

*Note: Make sure that the indexer is valid for the `IEnumerable`, array/list, otherwise, you would get `IndexOutOfRangeException`.*

---

With *System.Linq*

```
@Model.ApplicationUserVM.Single().ProfilePicture
```

*Note: Using `.Single()` would throw exception if `IEnumerable` contains more than one element.*

```
@Model.ApplicationUserVM.First().ProfilePicture
```

---

With loop:

```
@foreach (var user in Model.ApplicationUserVM)
{
    <div>@user.ProfilePicture</div>
}
```

Same goes for the rest that you are trying to access the property from `T` item.

Comment: I see IENumberable is for doing a list of some sort. I was watching a video about how to use multiple models in a view and they kept using the foreach loop, while using IEnumberables. So i thought that's what i had to use, now i took it away and it works like normal